# SQLSTATE error deploying a Laravel app to Heroku with Postgres

Tags: laravel, heroku

I followed the steps listed [here](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/deploying-a-laravel-application-to-heroku/) and it works mostly fine, but when setting and migrating the database gets me the following errors:

[image]

Here are the files I've configured:

**Procfile**

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

**database.php** (in config/)

```
<?php    

$url = parse_url(getenv("postgres:etc."));

$host = $url["host"];
$username = $url["user"];
$password = $url["pass"];
$database = substr($url["path"], 1);

return [
  'default' => 'pgsql',

  'connections' => [
    'pgsql' => [
      'driver'   => 'pgsql',
      'host'     => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["host"],
      'database' => substr(parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["path"], 1),
      'username' => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["user"],
      'password' => parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"))["pass"],
      'charset'  => 'utf8',
      'prefix'   => '',
      'schema'   => 'public',
    ],
  ]
]
```

Is there a step I'm missing or something wrong with my code? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, If you are a little on the down side, like I am. Wherever it says `DATABASE_URL` **DO NOT** actually replace it with the URL you get from Heroku. Just leave it as is and it will work fine.